# Colliding proton-proton and antiproton-antiproton?

Tags: particle-physics, particle-accelerators

Would there be any difference in the measurable observables between collisions of proton-proton and antiproton-antiproton?

I guess that colliding protons with anti-protons enable far more quark-antiquark interactions, so I guess that antiproton-antiproton collisions allow us to investigate the couplings of antiquarks?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176240/why-does-gg-fusion-dominate-over-q-qbar-annihilation-at-the-lhc

Comment: They have seen CP and T symmetries violated in mesons but not in antiprotons so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collision between a proton and proton, would be most likely identical to antiproton-antiproton collision. This is because as far as scientists know protons and antiprotons are identical(apart from charge and baryon number). Maybe instead of finding more quarks we would find more antiquarks. Proton and antiproton collision yield higher energy collisions(Maybe not significantly more if the beams are already high energy). This is because on top of the proton's and antiproton's kinetic energy, their mass energies are also converted into energy. The physicists would also "observe" quark antiquark annihilations. Scientists far the most part do not use antiproton collisions because it would most likely yield the same things as proton proton collisions. It is also expensive to try and make antiprotons.